# DisableWebEdit in a Scriban template

Tags: scriban

Is there a way we can use DisableWebEdit=true in a Scriban template?. Like on a cshtml page we can use

```
<title>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", Sitecore.Context.Item, new { DisableWebEdit = true })</title>`
```

This is the field I have `{{i_item.Title }}` but i want to make it DisableWebEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `{{i_item.Title }}` you can use the raw value of the field, that will only render the fields contents and will not add the experience editor ability:

```
{{i_item.Title.Raw }}
```

This will work for Single/Multi-line text and RichText fields.

For things like Images/Media, then you can construct the tag manually and use things like `sc_medialink` or the `media_url` to get the urls.

```
<img src="{{ sc_follow i_item ImageField | sc_medialink }}" />
```